# How to use IF statement on PHP MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Currently i'm doing my final year project about hotel management system. Now I'm stuck on using IF STATEMENT on PHP MYSQL query. I had create column named `roomtype` and `roomprice` under `reservation` table. The case are like this:

- If guest selected single on `roomtype`, it automatically shown the
  price on `roomprice`. Let say the price was 100.
- Then if guest selected superior, the price is 200.
- And then if deluxe was selected, the price is 300.

Below are my codes to store to database

```
 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('hotel_reservation3') or die('Could not select database');


    // Store query in variable
    $query = "INSERT INTO reservation (user_id,fullname,contactno,passport,roomtype,roomprice,num_of_rooms,dor,dco,bookingdate,length_of_stay)
                        VALUES
                        (
                        '".$_SESSION['user_id']."',
                        '".$_POST['fullname']."',
                        '".$_POST['contactno']."',
                        '".$_POST['passport']."',
                        '".$_POST['roomtype']."',
                        '".$_POST['num_of_rooms']."',
                        '".$_POST['dor']."',
                        '".$_POST['dco']."',
                        sysdate(),
                        DATEDIFF(dco,dor)
                        )";

    // Performing SQL query
    $result = mysql_query($query) 
    or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

    //echo "Success inserting record!";

    // Closing connection
    mysql_close($link);

    header("Location:reservation.php?success");
```

I'm using `POST` method which comes from a form. Below are partial code of the form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Full name*: <br>
            <input type="text" name="fullname">
        </li>
        <li>
            Contact No.: <br>
            <input type="text" name="contactno">
        </li>
        <li>
            IC/Passport*: <br>
            <input type="text" name="passport">
        </li>
        <li>
            Room Type*: <br>
            <select name="roomtype" id="roomtype">
            <option value="Single">Single</option>
            <option value="Superior">Superior</option>
            <option value="Deluxe">Deluxe</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            Number of Rooms*:</li>
            <input type="text" size="3" name="num_of_rooms">
            <br>
        <li>
            Date of reservation*: <br>
            <input type="text" size="12" id="dor" name="dor"/>
        </li>
        <li>
            Check-out Date*: <br>
            <input type="text" size="12" id= "dco" name="dco"/>
        </li>

          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" >
        <li>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Does anyone know the code?

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: You need to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) so you don’t create any more severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the ones you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. `$_POST` data **never** goes directly in a query. What you've done here is extremely risky.

Comment: I guess Bobby Tables won't be able to make a reservation. :(

Comment: so to clarify, your question is how to insert a different room price depending on which room type was selected? the number of columns doesn't match the number of values in the sql query so it will fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone has mentioned, please protect your SQL from injection.

You should calculate your price in PHP.

```
if($_POST['roomtype'] == "deluxe"){
    $roomprice = 300;
}else if($_POST['roomtype'] == "superior"){
    $roomprice = 200;
}else{
    $roomprice = 100;
}

// Store query in variable
$query = "INSERT INTO reservation (user_id,fullname,contactno,passport,roomtype,roomprice,num_of_rooms,dor,dco,bookingdate,length_of_stay)
                    VALUES
                    (
                    '".$_SESSION['user_id']."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fullname'])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contactno'])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passport'])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['roomtype'])."',
                    $roomprice,
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['num_of_rooms'])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dor'])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dco'])."',
                    NOW(),
                    DATEDIFF(dco,dor)
                    )";
```

Comment: put on the sql query?

Comment: does mysql_real_escape_string prevent from SQL injection?

Comment: I tried to change to other types of room (superior and deluxe) but it still 100

Comment: oh, sorry, you need to capitalize the roomtypes ("Superior", "Deluxe") in the php. Or you can change the value in the html to match.